# Setting up Eclipse for ArrayFire on Linux

Tags: c++, eclipse, arrayfire

I am trying to set up Eclipse (Mars 2.0) on Ubuntu 14.04 in order to compile and run C/C++ applications with ArrayFire utilities. I have already installed ArrayFire on my computer in /opt/ARRAYFIRE/arrayfire-3 and I'm trying first a very simple example using Eclipse to test ArrayFire performance.

I have created a simple C++ test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arrayfire.h>

using namespace af;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int N = 5;
    int nBytes = N * sizeof(int);
    int hostarr[N] = {3,1,4,1,5};
    float f[8] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};

    af::array aux(2,4,f);

    cout << "Well done!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I followed all the installation instructions of ArrayFire (including the prerequisites). Then, I set the ArrayFire headers "include" (-l) and libraries "lib" (-L) installed directories paths on the Eclipse project C/C++ Build Settings:

For my specific case:

- In GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes: /opt/ARRAYFIRE/arrayfire-3/include
- In GCC C Compiler -> Includes: /opt/ARRAYFIRE/arrayfire-3/include
- In GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries: /opt/ARRAYFIRE/arrayfire-3/lib

This is the normal procedure that I always have done for a new lib. However, when I trying to compile with gcc the next error ocurs:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib -L/opt/ARRAYFIRE/arrayfire-3/lib -o "classifier"  ./src/classifier.o   -lOpenCL
./src/classifier.o: En la función `main':
/home/ECLIPSE/classifier/Debug/../src/classifier.cpp:23: referencia a `af::array::array<float>(long long, long long, float const*, af_source)' sin definir
/home/ECLIPSE/classifier/Debug/../src/classifier.cpp:26: referencia a `af::array::~array()' sin definir
/home/ECLIPSE/classifier/Debug/../src/classifier.cpp:26: referencia a `af::array::~array()' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

(sorry for the spanish) "sin definir" = is not defined.

I know that the header are well-linked because I can see the declaration and Compiler works good, however the Linker fails.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem or what's happening?